# Parsing a file and using select case for the index value. Is there a better way?

Tags: .net, arrays, parsing

I am using .NETS textfieldparser to sort through a csv file.

As a proof of execution I am using the following code.

```
        Using csvfileparser As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("c:\V-7-FROM REMOTE02-SPT07 TO ANT12-H-ANT.csv")

        Dim csvalues As String()

        csvfileparser.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        csvfileparser.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        csvfileparser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

        While Not csvfileparser.EndOfData

            csvalues = csvfileparser.ReadFields()
            Dim indexValue As Integer = csvalues.Count

            Select Case indexValue
                Case 1
                    lbParsed.Items.Add(csvalues(0))
                Case 2
                    lbParsed.Items.Add(csvalues(0) & " " & csvalues(1))
                Case 3
                    lbParsed.Items.Add(csvalues(0) & " " & csvalues(1) & " " & csvalues(2))
            End Select
         End While
```

Is there a more efficient way to write all of an indexed array onto one line?

I've tried

```
For Each csvalue As String In csvalues
    lbParsed2.Items.Add(csvalue)
Next
```

Which wrote each item in the array to a new line.

The .csv's I am reading have a maximum index of 3 so I've covered all my bases there.
The code is executing just fine but I'm always eager to learn bigger and better.

Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Whenever you ask a question about _efficiency_ you open a vast can of worms. More efficient for the author? In terms of memory use?  CPU cycles? Versus multithreading? Over its maintenance lifecycle?

Comment: Thanks HABO, I suppose I mean coding efficiency.

Comment: You could loop through adding the values to an instance of `StringBuilder`. It avoids code for each specific count, but if the count never exceeds three then it's hard to argue. Tip: Always have a default clause (`case else`) to catch the unexpected and throw an exception with a useful message. It can save a lot of debugging time.

Comment: At the very least you could have a string temp (or string builder) for building the value to add and therefore only have one `lbParsed.Items.Add` call. This is more of a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) thing, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `String.Join(" ", csvalues)` instead of the Select Case and indexValue code.